# Не отправляется форма методом POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

Не могу понять, почему не отправляются данные формы, если использую метод POST. 
Если заменю POST на GET, то все работает.....

/index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Авторизация</h1>
<div id="wrapper">
    <form id="signin" method="post" action="/authorization" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Логин" required />
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Пароль" required />
        <button type="submit">&#xf0da;</button>
        <p>Забыли пароль? <a href="#">нажмите сюда</a></p>
        <p>Войти для просмотра? <a href="#">нажмите сюда</a></p>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

/authorization/index.php

```
    <?php

$login = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
echo $login;
echo '-------------------';
echo $password;
?>
```

Comment: Задавая вопрос, необходимо как можно подробнее описывать проблему. слова "не работает", "не отправляется", "барахлит", "не фурычит", "не взлетает", "косячит", "тупит", "лажает", "не хочет", "всё плохо"  таким описанием не является.

Comment: @Ипатьев а что не понятно?Я написал, что при использовании метода POST форма не отправляется, если просто заменю везде POST на GET, то все работает, куда подробней то))

Comment: Что значит не отправляется? не переносит на страницу? не нажимается кнопка? переносит на пустую страницу?

Comment: В консоль смотри. Скорее всего будет ругаться на CORS. Preflight check не проходит. Ну это я вангую.

Comment: @SergeySubbotin все нажимается, все переходит, массив POST пустой

Comment: Удалите атрибут `action`, добавьте вверху страницы `index.php` код: `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` и посмотрите, что он выведет.

Comment: @HakuKimura верно выводит введенные данные (array(2) { ["user"]=> string(4) "1234" ["pass"]=> string(8) "saxzczxc" })

Comment: @AlexSazonov ошибок нету никаких , смотрел вот так(ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action` путь полностью пропишите

```
<form action="/authorization/index.php"
```

ну или хотя бы так

```
<form action="/authorization/"
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо)